# Auth component in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a free installed instance of Cakephp 3.0 with several code examples, everything is working fine. Now I want to create a Auth component in ./src/Auth, concerning the documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects:)

Thats my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth; 
use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
class AlephAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Do things for OpenID here.
        // Return an array of user if they could authenticate the user,
        // return false if not.
    }
}
```

In AppContoller.php I initialize this component:

```
public function initialize() {
        $this->loadComponent('Auth');
        $this->Auth->config('authenticate', ['Aleph']);
    }
```

Calling the application URL in the browser shows:

Fatal error: Declaration of App\Auth\AlephAuthenticate::authenticate() must be compatible with Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate::authenticate(Cake\Network\Request $request, Cake\Network\Response $response) in /var/www/art/src/Auth/AlephAuthenticate.php on line 7

Any idea whats wrong here?

Thanks!

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message it is obvious. If you still have trouble understanding it [just paste the error message into a search engine](https://www.google.de/search?q=php%20fatal%20error%3A%20declaration%20of%20amust%20be%20compatible%20with&rct=j). This is the basic procedure for almost every error message if you don't know it and will probably *always* solve it. Guess it's in the php documentation as well.

Let me rephrase  the error message for you: The method signatures don't match. To get rid off the error message make them match.

Comment: Googeling the error message is what I did for a while now. The question for me is what exactly doesn't match here. The method authenticate is defined in the class BaseAuthorize.php:

abstract public function authorize($user, Request $request);

Comment: Add the namespaces on top: use Cake\Network\Request; and Response. Because just Request is not known inside your namespace. This will make it available as just "Request".  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php